# Is there a way to prevent page redirection caused by ads?

Tags: javascript, apache

My site is using Javascript ads code, and sometimes one of the ads redirects the page, and this is not a good practice according to Google (I got banned temporarily by Google until I solved the issue on my site).

Is there a way to prevent external Javascript redirect on the site (beside remove the ads)? Can you do this on the Apache configuration side to keep the domain in the address bar unchanged?

Comment: I understand the problem but I'm not sure about what you want Apache to do for you. Do you want to add a filter that modifies the JavaScript code you serve? Is ad code always local?

Answer (score 3):

Working on the assumption that the adverts load external code:

> Can you do this on the Apache configuration side to keep the domain in the address bar unchanged?

No. The advert isn't coming from your server. Your server can't influence it.

> Is there a way to prevent external Javascript redirect on the site (beside remove the ads)?

No. The script will be loaded into the global scope and you have no opportunity to block access to things it might use to redirect.

---

Removing the ads is the only real option. Don't use advertising platforms that do a bad job of filtering out adverts that use such shady practises.

Answer (score 0):

You can place the advertiser tag inside an iframe and add the sandbox attribute on the iframe.

In the sandbox attribute you specify which capabilities you grant the iframe.
Enter any capabilities you want but omit the *allow-top-navigation* navigation option and it will not allow it to navigate your site.

You can see all available attribute options here:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Scroll down to the sandbox explanation.

Know that if you put *sandbox=""* nothing will be allowed because only what you specify will be available for the iframe - and it is a problem for ads. Some advertiser might even serve ads for 100% crippled iframes.

Comment: Most of adnetworks (if not all) specify in their TOS to put their ads code inside body or head tag. Probably could break their rules. Thanks for the suggestion though.